# filter data frame by applying conditions on different columns by pandas

Tags: pandas

I am looking for a way to filter df by the below conditions:

the value in `created_by` column equals the value in the `owner` column and `status` equals 'Active'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9HSb.jpg)

Comment: Please post the data here, not in image of it.

Comment: try `df[(df['created_by'] == df['owner']) & (df['status'] == 'Active')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
(df['created_by']==df['owner']) & (df['status']=='Active')
```

and please read the User Guide: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

the logic of the condition you want to implement is that you want to filter all the rows that their created_by value is different than their owner value and also the status should be active.

```
if ((customers_df["created_by"] == customers_df["owner"]) & (customers_df["status"] == "Active")):
    # do your  Business logic
```